# Code works if all is in MainActivity but not with two classes

Tags: android, class, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have two classes MainActivity and WordBase . The code doesn't work but when i copy  it from WordBase class to MainActivity it works.
Here are the two classes

```
public class WordsBase {
private Activity context=null;
private View myView;

//  Type of words that user wants to search
private final String Noun="Nomen",Adjectives="Adjectives",Verbs="Verben";


 public WordsBase(Activity context)
     {
        this.context= context;
    }

     // creat the list menu that lets User to choose what type of words wants to search
    public void create () {

       LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.words_base, null);
       Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

       List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
       arr.add(Noun);
       arr.add(Adjectives);
       arr.add(Verbs);

       ArrayAdapter<String> menu_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);
       sp1.setAdapter(menu_Adapter);

   }

}
```

and here is the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.words_base);
    WordsBase menu =new WordsBase(this);
    menu.create();

   }
}
```

Comment: show the code in which it didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you forget add the view to main activity.

you can return the view like this

public view create (){

...
 return myView;
}

and in main activity you get the outside relativelayout   layout.addview(menu.create());

Comment: setContentView(new WordsBase(this).create());

Comment: public View create () {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.words_base, null);
        Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) myView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr.add(Noun);
        arr.add(Adjectives);
        arr.add(Verbs);

        ArrayAdapter<String> menu_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);
        sp1.setAdapter(menu_Adapter);

        return myView;
    }